# Editing publish profiles in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Applications

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, publish

I need to set up different publish properties depending on build configuration. I think it must be possible because of:

**1)** On Publish property page there are *disabled* combo boxes for configuration and platform. Why disabled?

**2)** In .csproj file there is section but this settings do not change on publish property page for defined configurations:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'TEST_INTERNAL' ">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl>D:\TestInternal\</PublishUrl>
    <InstallUrl>http://localhost/Resources/TestInternal/</InstallUrl>
    <UpdateUrl>http://localhost/Resources/TestInternal/</UpdateUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
<When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'TEST' ">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl>D:\TEST\</PublishUrl>
    <InstallUrl>http://localhost/Resources/Test/</InstallUrl>
    <UpdateUrl>http://localhost/Resources/Test/</UpdateUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
<Otherwise>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl>D:\PROD\</PublishUrl>
    <InstallUrl>http://localhost/Resources/Prod/</InstallUrl>
    <UpdateUrl>http://localhost/Resources/Prod/</UpdateUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Otherwise>
```

Any ideas why combo boxes are disabled or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I have the same question !
It looks like publishing profiles only work with Web Applications